# How can I end up in not visual mode after Coc inserts code?

Tags: plugin-coc

I am using Coc through vim-plug in Neovim. Coc allows the use of so-called code actions, which, when triggered, allows different Coc plugins to do stuff. For instance, when writing Rust, `coc-rust-analyzer` has the capability of filling in match arms (`match` statements in Rust are mostly glorified `switch` statements on enums; the plugin can fill in each case for you with empty code).

However, after it has finished I am left in visual mode. That's not desirable; I want to be left in the insert mode I was in when I triggered the codeaction. That's the way autocompletions usually work, I want to emulate that with the codeactions.

Using the following (almost) minimal init file:

```
language messages en_US.UTF-8
set nocompatible
call plug#begin()
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
call plug#end()
imap <c-p> <ESC><Plug>(coc-codeaction-cursor)a
```

the sequence of events described below follow:

> I am in insert mode, cursor at the `match` statement, with error message popup (sorry about the colors, and non-minimality of the match statement itself; the code is meant to read an md5 digest from stdin as an unsigned integer, and my minimal init file hasn't touched the `highlight`s):
>
> [image]
>
> I then go into insert mode and hit ctrl-p to make the codeaction menu pop up:
>
> [image]
>
> And after pressing enter, this is the result:
>
> [image]

The final `a` in my init file results in visual insert mode rather than visual mode (or maybe more correctly puts me in insert mode as the popup pops up). I tried inserting `<ESC>` in conjunction with the `a`, but that didn't help at all, presumably because whatever commands I type in that line of the init file happens between screenshots 1 and 2, while I want something to happen between 2 and 3.

I have tried a few other codeactions on the same file (specifically changing the `16` literal to binary `0b1000`, octal `0o20` or hex `0x10`, or adding explicit type annotations on the `let` statements, through basically the same process), and they don't put me in visual mode.

Comment: I think it should leave you in `select mode`, which looks like visual mode. It lets you replace what is selected as you type, which kind of what you want. Is it the case?

Comment: I might have misunderstood what mode you're trying to end up in.

Comment: @Biggybi It says "INSERT VISUAL" mode at the bottom of my third screenshot. The insert part is because of the `a` at the end of my init file. Without that, it would just say "VISUAL". Either way, if I start moving my cursor text will be visibly selected. That's not what I want. I want regular old insert mode. The one I naively tried to reach with the `a`. The mode I'm in in the second screenshot (if you ignore the popup box).

Comment: Have you tried `s` insead of `a` ?

Comment: @Biggybi Still leaves me in visual insert mode.